# Which term is more appropriate: Rate plan, Pricing plan or Tariff plan?

Tags: american-english, north-american-english

We are the provider of certain (on-line) services and we have different pricing for different user categories, depending on their volume of operations. Currently we use "tariff plan" as a term for pricing plan, but I think this term may be less common in the US than, say, "rate plan".

So, my question is: which term is more appropriate to describe a price plan for the consumer of online services, especially in American English. I personally tend to call it a "rate plan". Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Google Books is not the best indicator of usage in commercial settings, this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tariff%20plan,rate%20plan,price%20plan&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,tariff%20plan;,c0;.t1;,rate%20plan;,c0;.t1;,price%20plan;,c0) indicates that *tariff plan* is not very common in the US and *rate plan* is much more frequently used. *Price plan* may also be found, and even *price list* although that is more common for goods than services.

Very often the term **rates** is used as in [this example](http://www.att.com/global-search/search.jsp?App_ID=HOME&autoSuggest=FALSE&tabPressed=FALSE&q=rate%20plan#!/Shop/) (which was actually based on a search for *rate plan*).